# How to implement animated header in react-navigation with tabs and stacks

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I'm building an app that has a bottom tab navigation where each tab is also a stack navigator. I would like to animate the header both when switching tabs and when navigating inside the stack but I can't seem to figure it out correctly.

The navigation stack looks like this (can't show the actual code as I'm using @expo/router):

- TabsNavigator

  - TabA: StackNavigator
  - TabB: StackNavigator
  - TabC: StackNavigator

There are two approaches I'm aware of but neither of them fits all the criteria:

1. I could implement the header on the Tab navigator level (`headerShown: false` in stack navigators). This will keep the header on the top of the UI and when navigating between the tabs I can update the background color of the header but the back button is broken as it does not take the nested stack navigator into an account (so navigating inside the stack does not display a back button in the header)
2. I could implement the header on each of the Stack navigators (`headerShown: false` in tab navigator). This will make the back button work but now each tab has its own header so when navigating between them it is not possible to animate the background color.

I've spent way more time than I'm willing to admit on this and I still can't see a way to do it properly. Is implementing a custom navigator the only way to have both working back button and header animations in this scenario?